# nHibernate Criteria ---- Use of Expression.sql

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, expression

I need to do a query which checks a column in a table of type integer. how can i use expression.sql(nHIbernate Criteria API) to get all the rows matches the given number.
Thank you,
Rey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to use `Expression.Sql`? Couldn't `Expression.Eq` work for you?

Reference [Criteria Queries](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/querycriteria.html)

Sample code:

```
IList cats = sess.CreateCriteria(typeof(Cat))
    .Add( Expression.Like("Name", "Fritz%") )
    .Add( Expression.Or(
        Expression.Eq( "Age", 0 ), //<---- here is the one you check for int equality
        Expression.IsNull("Age")
    ) )
    .List();
```